# New-NetIPAddress argument "-IPAddress" causing "Missing closing '}' in statement block or type definition" error

Tags: powershell, networking

I am trying to configure my local system's virtual switch from a `config.json` file that looks like this:

```
{
    "system_name":"demo_system",
    "version":"0.0",
    "network_setting":{
        "virtual_switch":{
            "internal":{
                "NATSwitch":{
                    "ip_address":"123.456.789.2",
                    "interface_alias":"vEthernet (NATSwitch)",
                    "internal_ip_interface_address_prefix":"123.456.789.0/24"
                },
                "Robot Switch":{
                    "ip_address":"987.654.321.2",
                    "interface_alias":"vEthernet (Robot Switch)",
                    "internal_ip_interface_address_prefix":"987.654.321.0/24"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The ps1 file `testing.ps1` that reads this file and sets up the virtual switch is this:

```
Param
(
    [string]$system_config = "C:\workspace\config.json"   
)


function assert-virtual-switch
{
    # $args[0] is the $networking_ht
    Write-Output "Checking the virtual switches"
    $ht = $args[0]
    $internal_switch_psobject = $ht["virtual_switch"].internal
    $internal_switch_ht = @{}
    $internal_switch_psobject.psobject.properties | Foreach-Object { $internal_switch_ht[$_.Name] = $_.Value }
    foreach ($internal_switch_key in $internal_switch_ht.Keys) {
        if (Get-VMSwitch | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq $internal_switch_key}) {
            # The switch already exist
            Write-Output "Internal Switch $internal_switch_key exists"
        }else{
            # Create the virtual switch
            Write-Output "Internal Switch $internal_switch_key doesn't exist, creating it now"
            $internal_switch_ip = $internal_switch_ht[$internal_switch_key].ip_address
            $interface_alias = $internal_switch_ht[$internal_switch_key].interface_alias
            $internal_ip_interface_address_prefix = $internal_switch_ht[$internal_switch_key].internal_ip_interface_address_prefix
            [byte]$prefix_length = 24
            New-VMSwitch –SwitchName $internal_switch_key –SwitchType Internal
            New-NetIPAddress -PrefixLength $prefix_length –IPAddress "$internal_switch_ip" -InterfaceAlias "$interface_alias"
            New-NetNat –Name $internal_switch_key –InternalIPInterfaceAddressPrefix $internal_ip_interface_address_prefix
        }
    }
}

$sys_ps_object = Get-Content $system_config | Out-String | ConvertFrom-Json
$sys_ht = @{}
$sys_ps_object.psobject.properties | Foreach-Object { $sys_ht[$_.Name] = $_.Value }
# At this point, the system config is converted to a hash table, we can read from it like such:
foreach($sys_config_key in $sys_ht.Keys){
    if ($sys_config_key -eq "network_setting"){
        # $networking_ht is a hashtabe of the networking setting
        $networking_ps_object = $sys_ht[$sys_config_key]
        $networking_ht = @{}
        $networking_ps_object.psobject.properties | Foreach-Object { $networking_ht[$_.Name] = $_.Value }
    }
}

assert-virtual-switch $networking_ht
```

As you can see, I've created a function `assert-virtual-switch` that makes sure the virtual switch exists locally and will create one if it doesn't exist. The input of this function is a hash table of the internal switch information extracted from config.json.

However, I've been running into this error:

**Error**

```
At C:\workspace\test\test_new_ipaddress\testing.ps1:39 char:69
+ ... "External switch $external_switch_key doesn't exist, creating it now"
+                                                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
The string is missing the terminator: '.
At C:\workspace\test\test_new_ipaddress\testing.ps1:20 char:14
+         }else{
+              ~
Missing closing '}' in statement block or type definition.
At C:\workspace\test\test_new_ipaddress\testing.ps1:16 char:64
+     foreach ($internal_switch_key in $internal_switch_ht.Keys) {
+                                                                ~
Missing closing '}' in statement block or type definition.
At C:\workspace\test\test_new_ipaddress\testing.ps1:6 char:1
+ {
+ ~
Missing closing '}' in statement block or type definition.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParseException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TerminatorExpectedAtEndOfString
```

I've pinpointed the problem to this line that creates and configures the ip address.

```
New-NetIPAddress -PrefixLength $prefix_length –IPAddress "$internal_switch_ip" -InterfaceAlias "$interface_alias"
```

If I don't include the `-IPAddress` argument like this:

```
New-NetIPAddress -PrefixLength $prefix_length -InterfaceAlias "$interface_alias"
```

the error doesn't show up anymore:

```
PS C:\workspace> .\testing.ps1
Checking the virtual switches
Internal Switch Robot Switch exists
Internal Switch NATSwitch exists
```

So it must be coming from how the cmdlet interprets the IP address since I've tried with and without the quotation mark around `$internal_switch_ip`.

On another note, if I run the code line by line directly in the Powershell Console, it works.

Does anyone have any ideas of why this happens?

**EDITS**

As per the solution @Lee_Daily provided, the problem was caused by having a mix of dash and em-dash. After I changed all my "–" to "-", the code works.

Comment: Hi, so the IP you are trying to set are invalid. This might be an issue if `New-NetIpAddress` does an validation. But the errors look strange if this should be the issue

Comment: @benniz The actual IP addresses are something else, I just changed them to these for safety purpose

Comment: generally speaking, you do NOT want to wrap $Vars in double quotes. that triggers the `.ToString()` method ... and may not give you what you want. what happens if you **_remove the double quotes_**?

Comment: The first error in the output mentions **external switch** but all of your code references **internal switch** - it’s possible the syntax error is in *that* code instead and is just propagating down into the internal switch code. Could you confirm the error you’re seeing?

Comment: @Lee_Dailey Hi, I've tried removing the double quotes, and the same thing still happens

Comment: @mclayton It's another error in the code. I've fixed that and the error on 'missing closing }' still remains.

Comment: @terryxychan - good! that simplifies the situation a tad. [*grin*] all that i can think of now is an embedded character in that line that doesn't display - but triggers errors when interpreted. was any of the code copied from a web page OR from an MS document? i ask since both of those are notorious for converting things like a dash into an em-dash or straight quotes into curved quotes.

Comment: @terryxychan - can you update the question with the error text you see now? There might be some details that help work out what's happening.

Comment: @Lee_Daily - it *is* indeed the em-dash / en-dash issue - nice catch. ```–IPAddress``` is an em-dash in ```New-NetIPAddress```. I think the ```–InternalIPInterfaceAddressPrefix``` in the next line is as well - do you want to write up an answer?

Comment: @Lee_Daily- confusingly, if you cut&paste the code into a powershell.exe console it converts them into regular hyphens, which is why that works.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey oh my god, that's exactly the problem. There're 2 types of dashes in my code. After I changed them, they work. Life saver!

Comment: @terryxychan - you are most welcome ... i have spent hours trying to figure out similar glitches from copy-n-paste operations. glad to have helped! [*grin*]

Comment: "_The actual IP addresses are something else, I just changed them to these for safety purpose_" There are three defined IPv4 address blocks to use for such things: `192.0.2.0/24`, `198.51.100.0/24`, and `203.0.113.0/24`. Use of addresses in those ranges tells people that you are giving examples, not actual addresses that you are trying to use. You can also use addresses in those ranges to test things in a lab. See the _[IANA IPv4 Special-Purpose Address Registry](https://www.iana.org/assignments/iana-ipv4-special-registry/iana-ipv4-special-registry.xhtml)_.

Comment: @RonMaupin Thanks for the advice, I'll keep that in mind :)